# Cannot add value to Object

Tags: java, android

So I create object in MainActivity as field, and in onCreate I call method to load data from firecloud. In load data method, I add the value for object that I declare as field in MainActivity, but still when I checked the value from object it'll error with NullPointerException, here's the simplified code:

EDIT: Add firebase logic

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Layanan UP;
    Layanan GU;
    Layanan LS;
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    String TAG = "a";

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            loadData(extras);

            //I add new log
            try {
                UP = extras.getParcelable(UPParcelable);
                UP.getNama();
                Log.d(TAG, "Check if object not null after loadData() " + UP.getNama());
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Null pointer message: " + e);
            }

        }
    }

    //loadData() look below
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the UP still doesn't have any value?
I hope there'll be some enlightenment, amen

How to fix this?
Thank you

EDIT 3: Here's the actual loadData() code I'm making

```
    public void loadData(final Bundle extrasBundle){

        mFirebase.collection("panduan_layanan")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null){
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen error", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                            if (doc.exists()){
                                if (doc.get("nama").equals("UP")){
                                    try {
                                    UP = doc.toObject(Layanan.class);
                                    extrasBundle.putParcelable(UPParcelable, UP);
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Success add " + UP.getNama());
                                    Log.d(IFDOC, "Check if object not null inside for loops, the value is " + UP.getNama());
                                    } catch (NullPointerException nep){
                                        nep.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                if (doc.get("nama").equals("GU")){
                                    try {
                                    GU = doc.toObject(Layanan.class);
                                    extrasBundle.putParcelable(GUParcelable, GU);
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Success add " + GU.getNama());
                                    Log.d(IFDOC, "Check if object not null inside for loops, the value is " + GU.getNama());
                                    }catch (NullPointerException nep){
                                        nep.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                if (doc.get("nama").equals("LS")){
                                    try {
                                    LS = doc.toObject(Layanan.class);
                                    extrasBundle.putParcelable(LSParcelable, LS);
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Success add " + LS.getNama());
                                    Log.d(IFDOC, "Check if object not null inside for loops, the value is " + LS.getNama());
                                    } catch (NullPointerException nep){
                                        nep.printStackTrace();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            Log.d(OUTSIDEFOR, "Check if object not null from OUTSIDEFOR, the value is " + UP.getNama());
                            UP.getNama();
                        } catch (NullPointerException nep){
                            nep.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "loadData: " + UP.getNama());
        } catch (NullPointerException nep) {
            nep.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Null Pointer Exception inside loadData() body " + nep);
        }
    }
```

Here's the output from logcat

```
2020-05-10 15:00:42.998 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.kppnbandungi.plkbi.Layanan.getNama()' on a null object reference
2020-05-10 15:00:43.002 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi D/a: Null Pointer Exception inside loadData() body java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.kppnbandungi.plkbi.Layanan.getNama()' on a null object reference
2020-05-10 15:00:43.003 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.kppnbandungi.plkbi.Layanan.getNama()' on a null object reference
2020-05-10 15:00:43.005 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi D/a: Null pointer message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.kppnbandungi.plkbi.Layanan.getNama()' on a null object reference
2020-05-10 15:00:43.936 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi D/a: Check if object not null inside for loops, the value is GU
2020-05-10 15:00:43.948 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi D/a: Check if object not null inside for loops, the value is LS
2020-05-10 15:00:43.956 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi D/a: Check if object not null inside for loops, the value is UP
2020-05-10 15:00:43.956 5008-5008/com.kppnbandungi.plkbi D/a: Check if object not null from OUTSIDEFOR, the value is UP
```

Comment: Not the obj1, but the String TAG is null.

Comment: Hm, after I give TAG value, still it says NullPointerException @hata

Comment: Please, update your question to add the error log.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I updated it @hata

Comment: `doc.toObject()` is returning `null`

Comment: Sadly, the Log.d inside the loadData method shows that doc.toObject() has value because when obj1.getFieldName() return the value not null @DavidWasser

Comment: Well, somehow `obj1` is getting set to `null1` between the time you call `loadData()` and the time you try to log it in `onCreate()`. Is `obj1` defined locally inside `loadData()`? perhaps you have hidden the member variable with a local variable of the same name

Comment: obj1 is declared as field in MainActivity, not locally. Somehow after I read some material, it is related about pass by reference thingy in Java. But still as beginner I just want to pass the value to obj1 @DavidWasser

Comment: Let's go back. The error message you posted says "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.abs.myproject.ObjClass.getFieldName()' on a null object reference." This method is called in the `Log.d()` method call in `loadData()`. This implies that `obj1` is `null` after `doc.toObject()` is called, so your statement that the log output gives non-null value must be wrong. Or something else. Please check again and add the entire exception with stack trace from the logcat to your question.

Comment: Just edit your question and add the logs from logcat please.

Comment: There is still no stacktrace. Add the complete stacktrace from the logcat and other relevant logcat messages.   If you are not going to provide the information we are asking for, I doubt that we will be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks I am still fiddling with logcat, because it doesn't show anything